# Why is this NSPanel released with "close" button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

My NSPanel in IB has "release when closed" unchecked.

"Visible at Launch" is also unchecked.

I fade the NSPanel in with the following (activated by dragToButton) and it works fine

```
- (IBAction)dragToFile:(id)sender

{        

    DragImageView *accessory = [[[DragImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,71,63)] autorelease];
    [accessory setMainContentFolder:self.mainInstallFolder];

    [self.dragToFile setFloatingPanel:YES];
    [self.dragToFile makeKeyWindow];

    [dragImage setMainContentFolder:self.mainInstallFolder];
    NSRect frame = dragToFile.frame;
    NSRect mainFrame = self.window.frame;
    frame.origin.x = mainFrame.origin.x + 550;
    frame.origin.y = mainFrame.origin.y + 360;
    [dragToFile setFrame:frame display:NO];

    //set fade anim params
    NSDictionary *fadeInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 dragToFile, NSViewAnimationTargetKey,
                                 NSViewAnimationFadeInEffect, NSViewAnimationEffectKey,
                                 nil];
    //create fade instance
    NSViewAnimation *fadeIn = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: fadeInDict, nil]];

    [fadeIn startAnimation];
    [fadeIn release];
```

But if I close the window on the window's toolbar it triggers the following from a windowWillClose notification

```
- (void) dragToFileWindowDidClose:(id)sender
{
    [dragToFile setAlphaValue:0.0]; //make nspanel 0 alpha so it can fade in again
    [dragtoButton setState:NSOffState];

}
```

The window closes but completely disappears and doesn't come back on the next dragToButton click.

The NSPanel has the following property

`@property (retain) IBOutlet NSPanel *dragToFile;`

So I'm pretty sure that the window is getting released, but I dont know why because I deselected that option.

Comment: NSPanel's by default should not be released when they are closed. Maybe you're missing an `-orderFront:` call?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[dragToFile setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];` manually, first.

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. Now I'm wondering if the object is actually being released or if it's another issue at hand.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to note as I continue to diagnose your issue here, is that you have a method and an object with the same name. Never a semantic advantage-- you may want to modify the name of one of the two.

Comment: Try showing/hiding it without animations first, and see how that works. The animations could be wonky-- not sure how, yet, but that has happened to me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I solved it.

Instead of `[self.dragToFile makeKeyWindow];`

`[self.dragToFile makeKeyAndOrderFront:dragToFile];`

Not sure why this works and the other doesn't, but it works flawlessly now.

Thanks.